# Print a sequence using VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I want to print letter "A" in the cells corresponding to this formula:

1+3*1 = 4

4+3*2 = 10

10+3*3 = 19

I want to enter "A" in the cells A4, A10, A19. I want to do this for 25 cells.

How to do that

Comment: and which are those other 24 cells?

Comment: @user3598756 This sequece only is the cell no. A1,A4,A10 shows "A". So, I want to fill remaining 22 cells with "A"

Comment: @user3598756 total 25 "A" should be there in that column

Comment: I don't get you: what is the final range to be filled with "A"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to test if you are not going to far though :

```
Sub test_matangraj()
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim Col As Long
Col = 1

For i = 1 To 25
    Col = Col + i * 3
    If Col < Columns.Count Then
        Cells(1, Col) = "A"
        For k = 1 To i - 1
            If Col + k < Columns.Count Then Cells(1, Col + k) = "A"
        Next k
    Else
        MsgBox "Number of columns excedeed!" & vbcrlfr & _
                "Col: " & Col, vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Works Great!!! Thanks. Also, I want to Enter "A" as many time in the next column as it goes on increasing. suppose after A4 is the 2nd time is there, then in A5 also "A", if A10 (coming 3rd time), then A11 and A12 should also have "A".. Please help. it's really very ugent... thanks

Comment: @matangraj : I'm in such a good mood that I ignored your "urgent", it is very badly appreciated here to ask something saying it's urgent, so avoid it! Enjoy! ;)

Comment: I know, but please help. I hope you understand the problem. A1 contains "A", then A4(coming second time) next, so A5 also "A", then A10 (coming 3rd time), so A11, A12 also contains "A". like this I want to do

Comment: Compile error. Invalid next control variable reference

Comment: @matangraj : Corrected! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135254/discussion-between-matangraj-and-r3uk).

Comment: hi
you're genius
can you do me a little more favor
Same as "A", now i want to fill "B", just after the "A". in same sequence

Comment: @matangraj : Ask another question and add a clear explanation as well as a screenshot of the expected output for the 1st 3 of the sequence

Comment: can we move this discussion to chat, please?

Comment: I have added image. For "A" you have given correct solution. same i need for "B" and "C".

Comment: I'm not spamming. If you can help then please do. I want "B" to be printed after "A" in same sequence

Comment: Your solution starts with cell A4. In cell A1, "A" should be there. then start the sequence. can you modify it

Comment: @matangraj : Change `For i = 1` to `For i = 0`. I won't help furthermore on that question

Comment: @matangraj : Stop nagging me please, ask another question.

Comment: I know you don't know the solution. It's ok. Thanks for all the previous stuff